How to disable "Create Pull Request" link in WebStorm notifications
I want to get rid of this link, it's really annoying. Previous versions of WebStorm didn't have it. I prefer to create pull requests inside the GitHub interface
Maybe there is some setting that allows you to disable this link.
Maybe this can be changed via some configuration file inside the IDE. Experts are needed here

